# Protecting Static Resource in MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to protect/secure my html files in MobileFirst v7.0. We are currently implementing the static resources.

When we access the files (ex. domain/.../apps/services/www/.../mobilewebapp/default/app/modules/update-password/update-password.html) directly without authentication, it was a success, we can't access the files directly anymore.

But when we login to the actual page we are receiving the error below and we can't proceed to the next page.

[image: Error]

[image: URL Patterns]

Comment: For securing static resources in 7.0, Classic security model suggests "Protecting static resources" .A static resource is a URL that is loaded from the MobileFirst Server instance, 

Protecting a static resource means that MobileFirst Server requires authentication at any attempt to browse to the specified URL.
The static resources and their protection can be defined in the authenticationConfig.xml file.

<staticResources>
    <resource id="mobileFirstConsole" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
        <urlPatterns>/console*</urlPatterns>
    </resource>
</staticResources>

Comment: refer the link https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/authentication-security/authentication-concepts/classic-security-model/#protectStatic for more details

Comment: @KavithaVaradarajan, have you seen my attached image? I think what's in your comment is exactly what we did.

Comment: Can you clarify that the <resource> above is wrapped in to "<staticResource>" and added to authenticationConfig.xml ?

Comment: Can you upload your project to a file sharing service and provide the link here

Comment: @KavithaVaradarajan, yes it is wrapped in <staticResources> and its in my authenticationConfig.xml.

Comment: @Srik, sorry but we can't upload our project.

Comment: Can you try removing * at the beginning of URL , (ie)  <urlPatterns>/app/modules/update-password*;/app/modules/dashboard*</urlPatterns>

Comment: @KavithaVaradarajan, still same problem.

Comment: Ok, I suspected if some Schema validation issue which does not seem to be the case.  I need to see what the server returns on authentication to help you further. If you can share what the server returns with / without staticResources .

Comment: If you can recreate the same problem with a sample project with similar configuration, you can upload this